# How to animate opening/closing dialogs within whole application (or activity)?

Tags: android, animation, dialog

I have basic knowledge of animations, but how to set globally same animations for opening/closing dialogs within my app?

I have a preference screen with toolbar on top (with some menu items). And clicking on menu, or preferences opens dialogs.

How to set same dialog animations within my app, or at least within certain activity? So whatever dialog I open, it will always be same animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a theme for your dialogs with the desired animations and apply it to your app's theme in **styles.xml** like this:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- Apply your custom dialog theme here. -->
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/CustomDialog</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/CustomDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomDialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/slide_out_right</item>
</style>
```

That will apply the enter and exit animations to all of your dialogs ✌I just tested it myself and it worked, let me know if it works for you

Comment: thats all? It doesnt work...I aplied style APptheme to my activity (and also to my application) but no change whatsover...Do you make some changes in code also?

Comment: Ok, u were almost right. Instead <item name="android:dialogTheme"> you need to use <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">. Weird...But now it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad I gave you a clue maybe it didn't work for you because of the type of dialog you're using, my solution works with DialogFragments but you say the property android:alertDialogTheme worked for you... that means you're opening AlertDialogs? anyways, I updated my answer to support both now 

Answer (score 0):

Use this in alert dialog,

```
    if (alertDialogBuilder.getWindow() != null)
            alertDialogBuilder.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogTheme; //style id
```

In styles.xml define above Dialog Theme like below:

```
 <style name="DialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_left</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_right</item>
</style>
```

**Happy Coding :)**